HsbColor: a class representing a HSB/HSV color
I was looking for a way to adjust saturation and lightness of java.awt.Colors that don't expose that kind of API
I wrote my own HsbColor class. It's a tiny, simple, easy-to-follow class. It's not a subclass of Color (good), not even a wrapper (good?). However, it provides a convenient toColor() method that allows you to (indirectly) pass it to AWT/Swing methods that expect Color
It's an immutable class that returns a new instance on each increase/decreaseX() call. I was inspired by java.util.time types that do a similar thing in their plusDays() etc. methods
The basic flow would be to pass a Color, adjust its saturation/brightness and call toColor() to be able to use the adjusted color in Swing GUI. Which almost makes it sort of a service/utility class
It's so tiny and simple, I wasn't sure I should submit it for review, but I figured it may still be of value to me. Unfortunately, we don't practice code review in our development team, but I still want to get feedback somewhere (it's how I can become a better coder)
Sorry, no tests this time
package demos.color;

import java.awt.*;

/**
 * A type representing a HSB/HSV color — a color defined by three key properties: {@code hue}, {@code saturation}, and {@code brightness}.
 */
public class HsbColor {
    private final float hue;
    private final float saturation;
    private final float brightness;

    public HsbColor(Color color) {
        // if it was Java 22 where I don't have to call this/super the first line, I would do this in a single constructor
        this(Color.RGBtoHSB(color.getRed(), color.getGreen(), color.getBlue(), null));
    }
    
    private HsbColor(float[] hsbValues) {
        this(hsbValues[0], hsbValues[1], hsbValues[2]);
    }

    public HsbColor(float hue, float saturation, float brightness) {
        this.hue = hue;
        this.saturation = saturation;
        this.brightness = brightness;
    }

    /**
     * A shorthand for {@code increaseSaturationByPoints(10)}.
     *
     * @see #increaseSaturationByPoints(int)
     */
    public HsbColor increaseSaturation() {
        return increaseSaturationByPoints(10);
    }

    /**
     * A shorthand for {@code decreaseSaturationByPoints(10)}.
     *
     * @see #decreaseSaturationByPoints(int)
     */
    public HsbColor decreaseSaturation() {
        return decreaseSaturationByPoints(10);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new {@code HsbColor} instance with {@code saturation} equal to this {@code saturation} plus the
     * given number of percentage points (within the 0 to 100 bounds).
     * <p>
     * For example, if this {@code saturation} is 60, calling {@code increaseSaturationByPoints(25)}
     * returns a {@code HsbColor} object with {@code saturation} of 85 (60 + 25).
     */
    public HsbColor increaseSaturationByPoints(int points) {
        return adjustSaturation((float) points / 100);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new {@code HsbColor} instance with {@code saturation} equal to this {@code saturation} minus the
     * given number of percentage points (within the 0 to 100 bounds).
     * <p>
     * For example, if this {@code saturation} is 60, calling {@code decreaseSaturationByPoints(25)}
     * returns a {@code HsbColor} object with {@code saturation} of 35 (60 - 25).
     */
    public HsbColor decreaseSaturationByPoints(int points) {
        return adjustSaturation((float) -points / 100);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new {@code HsbColor} instance with {@code saturation} equal to this {@code saturation} increased
     * by the given percentage (within the 0 to 100 bounds).
     * <p>
     * For example, if this {@code saturation} is 60, calling {@code increaseSaturationByPercent(25)}
     * returns a {@code HsbColor} object with {@code saturation} of 75 (60 + 60 * 25 / 100).
     */
    public HsbColor increaseSaturationByPercent(int percent) {
        return adjustSaturation(saturation / 100 * percent);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new {@code HsbColor} instance with {@code saturation} equal to this {@code saturation} decreased
     * by the given percentage (within the 0 to 100 bounds).
     * <p>
     * For example, if this {@code saturation} is 60, calling {@code increaseSaturationByPercent(25)}
     * returns a {@code HsbColor} object with {@code saturation} of 45 (60 - 60 * 25 / 100).
     */
    public HsbColor decreaseSaturationByPercent(int percent) {
        return adjustSaturation(-saturation / 100 * percent);
    }

    private HsbColor adjustSaturation(float factor) {
        float newSaturation = Math.min(Math.max(saturation + factor, 0.0f), 1.0f);
        return new HsbColor(hue, newSaturation, brightness);
    }

    /**
     * A shorthand for {@code increaseBrightnessByPoints(10)};
     *
     * @see  #increaseBrightnessByPoints(int)
     */
    public HsbColor increaseBrightness() {
        return increaseBrightnessByPoints(10);
    }

    /**
     * A shorthand for {@code decreaseBrightnessByPoints(10)}.
     *
     * @see #decreaseBrightnessByPoints(int)
     */
    public HsbColor decreaseBrightness() {
        return decreaseBrightnessByPoints(10);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new {@code HsbColor} instance with {@code brightness} equal to this {@code brightness} plus the
     * given number of percentage points (within the 0 to 100 bounds).
     * <p>
     * For example, if this {@code brightness} is 60, calling {@code increaseBrightnessByPoints(25)}
     * returns a {@code HsbColor} object with {@code brightness} of 85 (60 + 25).
     */
    public HsbColor increaseBrightnessByPoints(int points) {
        return adjustBrightness((float) points / 100);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new {@code HsbColor} instance with {@code brightness} equal to this {@code brightness} minus the
     * given number of percentage points (within the 0 to 100 bounds).
     * <p>
     * For example, if this {@code brightness} is 60, calling {@code decreaseBrightnessByPoints(25)}
     * returns a {@code HsbColor} object with {@code brightness} of 35 (60 - 25).
     */
    public HsbColor decreaseBrightnessByPoints(int percentPoints) {
        return adjustBrightness((float) -percentPoints / 100);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new {@code HsbColor} instance with {@code brightness} equal to this {@code brightness} increased
     * by the given percentage (within the 0 to 100 bounds).
     * <p>
     * For example, if this {@code brightness} is 60, calling {@code increaseBrightnessByPercent(25)}
     * returns a {@code HsbColor} object with {@code brightness} of 75 (60 + 60 * 25 / 100).
     */
    public HsbColor increaseBrightnessByPercent(int percent) {
        return adjustBrightness(brightness / 100 * percent);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new {@code HsbColor} instance with {@code brightness} equal to this {@code brightness} decreased
     * by the given percentage (within the 0 to 100 bounds).
     * <p>
     * For example, if this {@code brightness} is 60, calling {@code decreaseBrightnessByPercent(25)}
     * returns a {@code HsbColor} object with {@code brightness} of 45 (60 - 60 * 25 / 100).
     */
    public HsbColor decreaseBrightnessByPercent(int percent) {
        return adjustBrightness(-brightness / 100 * percent);
    }

    private HsbColor adjustBrightness(float factor) {
        float newBrightness = Math.min(Math.max(brightness + factor, 0.0f), 1.0f);
        return new HsbColor(hue, saturation, newBrightness);
    }

    /**
     * Returns an instance of {@link Color} equivalent to this object.
     */
    public Color toColor() {
        return new Color(Color.HSBtoRGB(hue, saturation, brightness));
    }

    /**
     * Returns this {@code hue} represented by a degree between 0 and 360.
     */
    public float getHue() {
        return hue * 360;
    }

    /**
     * Returns this {@code saturation} represented by a percentage between 0 and 100.
     */
    public float getSaturation() {
        return saturation * 100;
    }

    /**
     * Returns this {@code brightness} represented by a percentage between 0 and 100.
     */
    public float getBrightness() {
        return brightness * 100;
    }
}

package demos.color;

import com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class HsbColorDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedLookAndFeelException, ClassNotFoundException,
            InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(WindowsLookAndFeel.class.getName());

        Color originalColor = UIManager.getColor("List.selectionBackground"); // Windows L&F: 0,120,215
        Color lighterColor = new HsbColor(originalColor)
                .increaseBrightnessByPercent(10)
                .decreaseSaturationByPercent(80)
                .toColor();
        Color darkerColor = new HsbColor(originalColor)
                .decreaseBrightnessByPercent(30)
                .decreaseSaturationByPercent(20)
                .toColor();

        System.out.println("Original Color: " + originalColor);
        System.out.println("Lighter Color: " + lighterColor);
        System.out.println("Darker Color: " + darkerColor);
    }
}


I think not having the Color class as a parent or a delegate was the correct choice. It would just have made the class overly complex without providing much functionality.
Don't import java.awt.* when you only need the Color class. It's a bad practise that eventually leads to import conflicts. Explicitly importing all dependencies also helps you notice when your class is becoming too complex (as the imports span tens or hundreds of lines). Maybe you should have a separate mapper for converting between HsbColor and java.awt.Color so that your users don't need the whole AWT dependency if you just want to use HSB colors?
You didn't specify what Java version you are using, but if possible the class should be a record. It automatically guarantees immutability and clearly conveys it to the user while also providing certain performance advantages. If this is not possible, the class should be final so that the immutability guarantee cannot be broken with mutable additions.
The constructors do not perform any input validation. The parameters should be checked that they are within the acceptable ranges. Also, the constructor parameters are values between 0 and 1 but the getters return a value between 0 and 100 (or 360). There should not be an inconsistency between the input and the output, both should use the same value range. You have not documented the accepted value ranges in the JavaDocs.
Should the hue be a value that is less than 360? From computing point of view, having two values (0 and 360) that represent the same thing creates complications downstream.
The names increaseBrightness and decreaseBrightness methods sound cumbersome, especially when you add the ByPoints suffixes. The Color class uses brighter and darker. Maybe follow that to be more compatible with classes the users probably are already familiar with? The saturation methods could then be saturate and desaturate.
Are you sure you need both the percentage and the percentage point adjustment? They make the API very cluttered. The percentage point adjustment seems like it could be removed if the constuctors and the getters used the same scale. The brighter/darker methods could then use percentages while the points adjustment could be replaced with addBrightness(float value) (which would accept a negative value).
